# Can I set the default retention time for log groups created in a AWS CDK v2 created pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aspect

I have an AWS VDK v2 based application stack that sets up a CodePipeline with different stages, application and all that, that works alright. But this setup creates quite some log-groups where the retention time is not set. As the log groups are not created by my cdk code, but under the hood by cdk itself, I cannot explicitly set the retention time.

So I tried to use `Aspects` to achieve that. I created the following:

```js
export class LogGroupRetentionChecker implements IAspect {

    prefix: String

    constructor(prefix: String) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    visit(node: IConstruct): void {

        console.log(`${(this.prefix)}: checking node ${node.constructor.name}`)

        if (node instanceof CfnResource) {
            console.log(`${this.prefix}: resource type ${node.cfnResourceType}`)
        }

        if (node instanceof CfnLogGroup) {

            console.log(`aspect found log-group ${node.logGroupName}, retention: ${node.retentionInDays}`);

            if (node.retentionInDays === undefined) {
                node.retentionInDays = 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the place where the pipeline is created, I then do this:

```js
Aspects.of(this.pipeline).add(new LogGroupRetentionChecker("pipeline"));
```

And If have one more call where I create a stage. For the aspect on the pipleine this shows for example

```
pipeline: checking node CodePipeline
pipeline: checking node Pipeline
pipeline: checking node Key
pipeline: checking node CfnKey
pipeline: resource type AWS::KMS::Key
pipeline: checking node Alias
pipeline: checking node CfnAlias
pipeline: resource type AWS::KMS::Alias
pipeline: checking node Bucket
pipeline: checking node CfnBucket
pipeline: resource type AWS::S3::Bucket
pipeline: checking node BucketPolicy
pipeline: checking node CfnBucketPolicy
pipeline: resource type AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
pipeline: checking node Role
pipeline: checking node CfnRole
pipeline: resource type AWS::IAM::Role
pipeline: checking node Policy
pipeline: checking node CfnPolicyConditional
pipeline: resource type AWS::IAM::Policy
pipeline: checking node CfnPipeline
pipeline: resource type AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
pipeline: checking node Construct
pipeline: checking node Construct
pipeline: checking node Role
pipeline: checking node CfnRole
pipeline: resource type AWS::IAM::Role
pipeline: checking node Policy
pipeline: checking node CfnPolicyConditional
pipeline: resource type AWS::IAM::Policy
pipeline: checking node Construct

...
```

So the aspect is called, but none of the `IConstruct`s that are visited is a `CfnLogGroup`.

My question now: How can I get these log-groups configured? If not by aspect, is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For log groups you can't access directly in CDK/Cfn, use a Lambda-backed [Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html) or [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) to put a retention policy using SDK calls.  CloudFormation will invoke your Lambda as part of the pipeline stack's deploy lifecycle.  Configure the Trigger/CR to run the Lambda only on stack create.

The Lambda's job is to:

1. Look up the log groups with [DescribeLogGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLogGroups.html). Filter by setting `logGroupNamePrefix: "/aws/codebuild/MyPipeline"`.
2. Invoke [PutRetentionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutRetentionPolicy.html) for each log group name.

##### Edit: Another Option

Another option is to create explicit log groups for each CodeBuild project in the pipeline.

Many pipeline constructs, including `ShellStep`, deploy a `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` resource under the hood. If we create a [LogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.LogGroup.html) with the desired retention days set, we can pass it to a project.

For indirectly created projects (like that underlying `ShellStep`) we must first use [escape hatch syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) to reference the underlying [CfnProject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.CfnProject.html) constructs. Then we pass our configured LogGroup name to the its [logsConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.CfnProject.html#logsconfig) property.

It's easier for an explicitly constructed `codebuild.Project`.  It accepts a `LogGroup` directly in the [logging:LoggingOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.LoggingOptions.html) prop.

Comment: for a new stack, are the log groups already existing on deploy? Or aren't they created when the deployed pipeline is run?  But having a lambda to set this up seems a good idea, maybe we're using that approach to handle all the loggroups from different pipelines.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch The pipeline's log groups are created indirectly as part of the stack's CodeBuild project resource deploys.  You won't find log group resources defined in the Cfn template that CDK creates, unless you created them explicitly (see edit).

Comment: We decided to go the way to have a scheduled lambda that checks the log groups that do not have a retention time set - not only from one pipeline as we have many. We have an application that does regular task, so we can add it there. And we mwill probably add other checks there as well. But many thanks for your answer

Comment: @P.J.Meisch  Glad to help. It would help me if you upvoted/accepted the answer.  I acknowledge you decided not to use a CDK approach, for reasons not stated in the OP.  But your question was "how can I do this in CDK?", which I answered.

Comment: Well, your answer in the end went into the direction to create dedicated log groups whereas I wanted to adjust the ones that are implicitly created. But if it makes you happy, I'll accept that.